# Remove file or directory from Terminal that is already gone in Finder

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, path, delete-file

I deleted some files/folders and moved some other folders around in my Finder. Now every time I open up terminal, the first 4 lines always list 4 files or directories like this:

```
-bash: cd: file-name: No such file or directory
-bash: cd: file-name: No such file or directory
-bash: cd: file-name: No such file or directory
-bash: cd: file-name: No such file or directory
```

I have tried to remove them using `rm` but just get the same message, restarting Terminal many times, and restarting my mac many times, etc I can't find them in Finder either. How do I clear terminal so it doesn't try to "look into" these non existing files or directories? I am thinking it is still reading in a path somehow, but I am fairly new to mac and terminal.

Comment: It looks as bash is trying to cd into these dirs as a part of its startup. Look into your bash config file(s) to find what is causing this.

Comment: ...namely [these files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files)

Comment: So I found them in my .bash_profile document when I launched it in my IDE. it lists the PATH and then lists the directories. How would I go about deleting these from the .bash_profile or PATH?

Comment: @TalonHughes just deleting the lines related to your files/folders from the bash_profile should work.

Comment: @NepCoder Perfect that worked! Thanks all!

Comment: @TalonHughes That's great. I added it as a answer for future references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your bash_profile for any reference to the deleted files. If there are any deleted files listed there, remove the lines from the file and save the bash_profile. Restart Terminal.